# R Loop Not Looping Through Each Data Group

Tags: r, loops

I'm attempting to run a loop for best fit models by groupings. I have it to the point where I can't seem to get the loop to run individually - it loops through and outputs several csv as expected, but the data within is the same for each file:

```
library(leaps)
library(dplyr)

#data
df = data.frame(matrix(rnorm(80), nrow=10))
df$state <- c('AL','AK','AR','AZ','CT')
state_list <- c('AL','AK','AR','AZ','CT')

for (state in state_list){
  data_filter <- subset(df, state = state)
  data_filter_u <- data_filter[c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)]
  data_sub <- regsubsets(X8~., data_filter_u, nvmax = 8)
  data_summary <- summary(data_sub)
  data_coef <- coef(data_sub,which.max(data_summary$adjr2))
  as.data.frame(t(data_coef))
  data_coef$state_used <- state
  write.csv(data_coef,paste0(unique(state),".csv"))
}
```

However - i get the same data for each file (same intercept, variables used and coefficients), and it's creating two unintended columns, 'stateAr','stateAZ','stateCT'.

```
+---+--------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+------------+
|   | X.Intercept. |     X2      |     X3      |     X4      |     X5      |     X7      |   stateAR    |   stateAZ    |   stateCT    | state_used |
+---+--------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+------------+
| 1 |  1.027070119 | 0.593400469 | 0.852107976 | 0.219067212 | 0.447761824 | 0.213681166 | -3.421259006 | -2.250303456 | -0.558997077 | AL         |
+---+--------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+------------+
```

I am trying to receive something like this, with just the state the looped through and the appropriate columns based on the best fit:

```
+---+--------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+------------+
|   | X.Intercept. |     X2      |     X3      |     X4      |     X5      |     X7      | state_used |
+---+--------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+------------+
| 1 |  1.027070119 | 0.593400469 | 0.852107976 | 0.219067212 | 0.447761824 | 0.213681166 | AL         |
+---+--------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+------------+
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: @ManuelBickel Gah, you're right, it was the subset and ==. It does loop through correctly now - if you want add your comment as an answer I'll accept - thanks for your time and help!

Comment: Added an extended answer and will therefore delete my comment... Hope it helps, good luck with your project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If my understanding is correct, I think that your subset command does not do what you intend to do. You might use something like

```
df[df$state == state, ]
```

to subset your `data.frame` by the current group of the loop. If you have several condititons you might use something like

```
df[df$state %in% c("AL", "AK"), ]
```

A side note regarding speed, I think direct subsetting without using `base::subset` is usually faster (please anybody correct me if I am wrong). See below benchmark for your example. If your data gets really large you might think about using `data.table`, which is even faster. However, due to the overhead of `data.table`, this would not make sense for your very small data set.

```
df = data.frame(matrix(rnorm(80), nrow=10))
df$state <- c('AL','AK','AR','AZ','CT')
state_list <- c('AL','AK','AR','AZ','CT')
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
(a = subset(df,state == "AL"))
,(b =df[df$state == "AL", ])
)
# Unit: microseconds
#                            expr     min       lq      mean   median       uq     max neval cld
# (a = subset(df, state == "AL")) 118.031 121.1885 128.32595 123.1625 125.9260 273.167   100  b
# (b = df[df$state == "AL", ])     92.372  95.9250  99.84874  97.1090  99.4775 215.139   100  a 
all.equal(a,b)
# [1] TRUE
```